# Changing Material Design Icon and Text to Primary Color

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

It is my first time using material design and whilst everything is working very affectly I was slightly confused with the icon colors.

In my App.xaml I have the following resource dictionaries;

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Grey.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Yellow.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

And on my form I have an icon and textblock;

```
        <DockPanel>
            <materialDesign:PackIcon x:Name="iconWarning" Width="25" Height="25" Margin="5" Kind="Warning" Foreground="OrangeRed" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="lblWarning" Text="Warning" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Padding="5" Foreground="OrangeRed"/>
        </DockPanel>
```

However, in my C# code I have a method which can change the theme in use, and also changes the primary and secondary colors. However, how can I set my textblock and icon to use the primary color similarly to how you can set with a colorzone for example using mode as oppsoed to having to use Foreground="OrangeRed";

```
Mode="PrimaryMid"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find the Primary* brush resources [here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/2740f14a814896d42032ae0013b765a8a0ec04c3/MaterialDesignColors.Wpf/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Grey.xaml):

```
<materialDesign:PackIcon x:Name="iconWarning" Width="25" Height="25" Margin="5" Kind="Warning"
                         Foreground="{StaticResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}" />
<TextBlock x:Name="lblWarning" Text="Warning" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Margin="5" Padding="5"
           Foreground="{StaticResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}" />
```